# Grab JavaScript console output with PhantomJS and evaluate it

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to parse the status page of my router to get the number of wlan devices. The page uses some JavaScript to get the status, so I tried to use PhantomJS, but had no luck.

This is the html source of the status page (status.html and status.js): http://pastebin.com/dmvptBqv

The developer tools of my browser show me this output on the console (anonymized):

```
([
{"vartype":"value","varid":"device_name","varvalue":"Speedport W 921V"},
{"vartype":"value","varid":"factorydefault","varvalue":"1"},
{"vartype":"value","varid":"rebooting","varvalue":"0"},
{"vartype":"value","varid":"router_state","varvalue":"OK"},
{"vartype":"value","varid":"bngscrat","varvalue":"0"},
{"vartype":"value","varid":"acsreach","varvalue":"0"},
```

[Full reference](http://pastebin.com/EdWBV77c)

How can I get this evaluated output out of PhantomJS? Maybe it is very simple and I just missed the part in the documentation.

I think that i have to use the evluate function, but have no idea what is the correct function for the document object to return the complete evaluation.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('blubb', function   (status) {

  var js= page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.???;
  });

  console.log(js);
  phantom.exit();

});
```

Comment: Have you tried registering to `page.onConsoleMessage`?

Comment: Hi, I tried `page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};` with a console log of `document.body.innerHTML;`, but didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't make sense if you say that the developer tools already show something in the console. Does `page.open(url, function   (status) { console.log("test"); phantom.exit(); });` print anything? If so, what about `page.open(url, function (status) { console.log(page.content); phantom.exit(); });`?

Comment: Hi, the first gives me `$ ./phantomjs test.js > test`. The latter one prints the html source, but the javscript was not executed, see here: [link](http://pastebin.com/fVmaZZWy)

Comment: a) What does the `status` say? b) Which PhantomJS version do you use? c) Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. d) Have you tried to wait a little before printing the page source/render a screenshot?

Comment: Waiting helped! The html output is fine now, but is it also possible to get the evaluated data like [here](http://pastebin.com/EdWBV77c)? This would be more helpful to get all status information. version is 1.9.8

Comment: @DanielS: you need to parse the html file, you should use cheeriojs for that. And you shouldn't write directly in phantomjs, but use phantomjs-node or another bridge, because phantomjs applications doesn't have all the modules of nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that you have is to get the console messages from the page into a single structure that you can do further processing on. This is easily done with the following code which waits indefinitely until the first console message appears and stops waiting as soon as no further messages appeared during 1 second.

```
var logs = []
    timeoutID;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    if (timeoutID) clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    logs.push(msg); // possibly also further processing
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
        page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
            console.log("CONSOLE: " + msg);
        };

        // TODO: further processing
        console.log(JSON.stringify(logs, undefined, 4));
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
};

page.open(url); // wait indefinitely
```

If each `msg` is valid JSON, then you can parse it immediately to get JavaScript objects. Change

```
logs.push(msg);
```

to

```
logs.push(JSON.parse(msg));
```